# Table views using XIB files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using separate .xib files for each table view with navigation controller. And when click the disclosure indicator of first table view it should show its corresponding data which is on another .xib file. So when I click on the indicator it goes to the next table view but my data are not showing it show a blank table view. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please paste some code here so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if u have set the data source of your detail tableView. Use breakpoints to find out whether data is being passed over or not.

Comment: thanks I have to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.I have the answer now.